# Launching activity not showing and not working in Android Studio

Tags: android

After building code, everything showing such as indexing. But after successful build not showing launching activity. I am using my device to run it.
It is happening suddenly. Till this evening it was working well but suddenly not working.
I did everything like restarting the Android Studio, restarting the Windows etc but not working.
What to do now?
Error Log :

```
2019-03-09 21:42:03.103 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1552147923.090:26769): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  pid=27880 comm="UNUSED_FILEAPKS" name="DynamiteModulesA.apk.prof" dev="ecryptfs" ino=131724 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c662,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-J730GM_8.1.0_0007 unfiltered
2019-03-09 21:42:03.103 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1552147923.090:26769): arch=40000028 syscall=328 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=e0e14ed0 a2=0 a3=c2c325f0 items=0 ppid=2693 pid=27880 auid=4294967295 uid=15010022 gid=15010022 euid=15010022 suid=15010022 fsuid=15010022 egid=15010022 sgid=15010022 fsgid=15010022 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="UNUSED_FILEAPKS" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:priv_app:s0:c662,c768 key=(null)
2019-03-09 21:42:03.104 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1552147923.090:26769): proctitle="com.google.android.gms"
2019-03-09 21:42:03.105 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1552147923.090:26770): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=27880 comm="UNUSED_FILEAPKS" path="/data/knox/data_de/150/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/c-0000004f-1549351248117/oat/DynamiteModulesC.apk.prof" dev="dm-1" ino=327700 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c662,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-J730GM_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
2019-03-09 21:42:03.316 28074-28074/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:03.531 7446-7461/? E/iss-mwServ:  extSDCardStackService Binder died, closing all fds
2019-03-09 21:42:03.900 3455-3930/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2019-03-09 21:42:03.939 3489-3489/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2 visible false
2019-03-09 21:42:03.939 3489-3489/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2 visible false
2019-03-09 21:42:04.579 28107-28107/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:04.821 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: exception : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.bsb.hike
2019-03-09 21:42:04.822 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: exception : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.imo.android.imoim
2019-03-09 21:42:04.823 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: exception : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.jiochat.jiochatapp
2019-03-09 21:42:04.868 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: DailySavingMB: existing Job to check ==>true
2019-03-09 21:42:06.420 6174-6174/? E/SEMS:MobileService_4.2.0.033: [BLog][2][BuddyPrecondition] fail CONDITION_SEMS_ACTIVATE
2019-03-09 21:42:08.668 3001-3105/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:12.751 27915-27945/? E/Finsky: [140087] flv.a(26): Unable to build selector: /storage/emulated/150/Download/marketenvs.csv (No such file or directory)
2019-03-09 21:42:13.243 27993-28029/? E/Finsky: [140090] flv.a(26): Unable to build selector: /storage/emulated/0/Download/marketenvs.csv (No such file or directory)
2019-03-09 21:42:13.448 3001-3581/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.453 3001-3581/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.454 3001-3581/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.461 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.466 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.467 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.474 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.479 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.480 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.659 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.667 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.668 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.676 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.683 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.684 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.691 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.697 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.697 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.704 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.710 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.710 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.952 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.958 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.958 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.965 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.971 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.971 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.978 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.984 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.984 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.993 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.998 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:13.999 3001-4620/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.005 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.011 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.011 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.019 3001-3581/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.024 3001-3581/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.025 3001-3581/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.032 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.037 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.038 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:14.579 28173-28173/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:14.918 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1552147934.910:26776): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=28200 comm="pool-7-thread-1" name="anr" dev="dm-1" ino=1114113 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:anr_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-J730GM_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
2019-03-09 21:42:14.918 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1552147934.910:26776): arch=40000028 syscall=317 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=30 a1=dd96b0b0 a2=8 a3=e10384dc items=0 ppid=2693 pid=28200 auid=4294967295 uid=10623 gid=10623 euid=10623 suid=10623 fsuid=10623 egid=10623 sgid=10623 fsgid=10623 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="pool-7-thread-1" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
2019-03-09 21:42:14.918 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1552147934.910:26776): proctitle="com.taptap"
2019-03-09 21:42:15.009 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:15.064 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:15.065 3001-4563/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=887100116 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
2019-03-09 21:42:15.101 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1552147935.090:26777): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=28204 comm="BUGLY_THREAD" name="uptime" dev="proc" ino=4026534918 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-J730GM_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
2019-03-09 21:42:15.101 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1552147935.090:26777): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=cae45750 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2693 pid=28204 auid=4294967295 uid=10623 gid=10623 euid=10623 suid=10623 fsuid=10623 egid=10623 sgid=10623 fsgid=10623 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="BUGLY_THREAD" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
2019-03-09 21:42:15.101 2679-2679/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1552147935.090:26777): proctitle="com.taptap"
2019-03-09 21:42:24.751 28243-28243/? E/FeatureClassSet: [#CMH#] Rubin package not supported 
2019-03-09 21:42:25.496 3001-3609/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 24598 [2019-03-09 21:42:25.496]
2019-03-09 21:42:27.223 3001-3138/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 2
2019-03-09 21:42:27.242 3455-3930/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2019-03-09 21:42:27.291 3489-3489/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2 visible false
2019-03-09 21:42:27.291 3489-3489/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2 visible false
2019-03-09 21:42:29.109 3455-3930/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2019-03-09 21:42:29.119 3455-3930/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2019-03-09 21:42:31.527 28272-28272/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:32.626 5855-28300/? E/SAMSUNGPAY: [UPISyncUtils] Failure in fetching device contacts/no contacts in device - Cannot sync with server
2019-03-09 21:42:32.734 28308-28308/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:32.999 1367-1367/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 1
2019-03-09 21:42:33.020 1367-1367/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
2019-03-09 21:42:34.876 28382-28382/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:36.199 28382-28382/? E/SamsungNotes$ST$LockPasswordUtils: isAvailableIris : com.samsung.android.sdk.SsdkUnsupportedException: This device is not supported Siris!!!
2019-03-09 21:42:36.706 28382-28382/? E/SamsungNotes$SDocService: stopSelf, callee: onStartCommand, after restore cache
2019-03-09 21:42:44.581 28421-28421/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-03-09 21:42:46.487 28444-28444/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
```

Answer (score 1):

> What to do now?
>   **Connect your phone in debugging mode and post error log of your app**

Comment: I added log, what should i do now ?

Comment: : /storage/emulated/150/Download/marketenvs.csv (No such file or directory)
2019-03-09 21:42:13.243 27993-28029/? E/Finsky: [140090] flv.a(26): Unable to build selector: /storage/emulated/0/Download/marketenvs.csv (No such file or directory)  These files are not present in this path or something like this

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: Instead of 150 put 0 (zero).

Comment: Any solution for it ?

Comment: I am running it in android device not emulator

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in your manifest file should be added.

Comment: 2019-03-09 21:42:04.821 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: exception : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.bsb.hike
2019-03-09 21:42:04.822 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: exception : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.imo.android.imoim
2019-03-09 21:42:04.823 28107-28107/? E/MEMExtService: exception : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.jiochat.jiochatapp. These 3 packages for PackageManagers are also invalid as per exceptions thrown.

Comment: It also indicates that the device you are using may not be compatible for the functionality that you want to use in your app. "2019-03-09 21:42:36.199 28382-28382/? E/SamsungNotes$ST$LockPasswordUtils: isAvailableIris : com.samsung.android.sdk.SsdkUnsupportedException: This device is not supported Siris!!!".

Comment: It was working till this evening, but now not working.

Comment: I tesed 2 phones after getting this

Comment: Well then, check for those packages, permissions and file paths. These are the only possible things found from your logcat.

Comment: Do not post comment too quickly before going through code again and again (go very slowly )  until you found some silly mistake(s) that should not be done.

Comment: Can you try enabling developer option in your mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Have you re chacked manifest for launching activity? Also have you tried a clean build ?